# Is it more efficient to have static classes than non static classes in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, object, static

In asp.net/c#, as a server side solution where multiple people connect to the site, I have multiple classes. However if they are left non static, I only end up creating one of those objects. I want to know if its more efficient to just make them static classes, or leave them as non static and create the 1 object and use that.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider using Dependency Injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: They do entirely different things, so comparing their performance isn't really relevant.  Either you need to have an instance of the type because you're leveraging instance fields, and the methods should be non-static, or there is no dependence on instance fields and they should be static *regardless* of performance as there is no dependence there.  Only one of the two actually represents what you're doing, use whichever that is.  Using the "other" option, when it doesn't make sense, wouldn't be worth doing even if it did have a minor performance difference.

Comment: More efficient than what? What is "efficiency"? Other metrics might be more important. Maintainability, readability and extensibility spring to mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of using static methods vs instantiating the class containing the methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202631/performance-of-using-static-methods-vs-instantiating-the-class-containing-the-me)

Comment: I think that depends on what are you trying to do with this class. Has only methods like an utility class?

Comment: @Win, why you suggest using Dependency Injection here?, I just simply don't get it. Maybe you're suggesting using the Singleton Pattern.

Comment: @NicolásKittsteiner *Most web applications* these days use Dependency Injection instead of instantiating/creating objects like old days. Besides, you can hardly find static classes except helper classes and extension methods. *Note: I'm not talking about Microsoft Frameworks.*

Comment: If you only ever have one instance of those classes, they should probably be singletons. Making them static won't make a difference in terms of performance (at least not a noticeable one)

Comment: What's unclear about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static classes would be faster.  Slightly.  But non-static classes give you immense flexibility, and it would be a shame to give it up.  You may never need it, but it's nice to know it's there if you do.

**Examples:**

You might someday want two or more copies of one of these classes.  What today is your whole universe can be a small part of tomorrow's system.  What today is *the* sun is, tomorrow, just one of 100,000 stars.

You might find it handy to pass a method a modified copy of the single instance.  This lets you put code written to work with the official, single instance to other uses.

Non-static classes can extend other classes and interfaces.  Several of your single-instance classes might want to implement an interface so they can substitute for each other at times.  And several may share the same functionality and want to inherit from another class.

(And there's bound to be a lot of other good reasons, too.)

Comment: Static classes are more efficient. Static classes are great for storing static data, shared by one or more class(process). If you want to have only one copy of data "of some thing", and make sure all other processes, classes, are feeding off the same source" static class", then use static class. Singleton classes can also be used for the same purpose.  I use static classes, and define some map, which can be updated by one or more process, and also shared by one or more...

Answer (score 2):

Class and static class are not interchangeable.

Your static classes are shared between requests to Your server. They also live as long as application domain.

Class instance is different and will be created separately for each request and each request will have its own data.

Static class can work slightly faster as there is no need to create instance each time, but difference in most cases is negligible. You can have data synchronization and memory usage issues with static class as data is shared between requests and stored longer.